# Selecionar dados mesmo que não conste em todas as tabelas

Tags: postgresql

possuo a seguinte `Query`:

```
SELECT 
    public.suprimento.suprimento, 
    public.estoque.numeroserie, 
    public.fornecedor.nome as fornecedor, 
    public.estoque.data as dataentrada, 
    public.estoque.numeronotafiscal,
    public.empresa.nome as empresa,
    public.entrega.data as datasaida,
    public.entrega.notafiscalhss,
    public.entrega.usuario,
    public.entrega.usuariohss,
    public.lotesretornosuprimento.dataretorno,
    public.lotesretornosuprimento.laudo,
    public.lotesgarantiastatus.numeroserieretornado
FROM
    public.estoque, 
    public.suprimento,
    public.fornecedor,
    public.entregaitem,
    public.entrega,
    public.empresa,
    public.lotesretornosuprimento,
    public.lotesgarantiastatus
where 
    public.suprimento.codigo = public.estoque.codigosuprimento and
    public.estoque.codigofornecedor = public.fornecedor.codigo and
    public.entregaitem.codigoestoque = public.estoque.codigo and 
    public.entregaitem.codigoentrega = public.entrega.codigo and
    public.empresa.codigo = public.entrega.codigoempresa and
    public.lotesretornosuprimento.numeroserie = public.estoque.numeroserie and
    public.lotesgarantiastatus.numeroserieenviado = public.estoque.numeroserie
```

Que me retorna todo o percurso de do suprimento desde de o momento em que o mesmo é comprado até o retorno para o nosso fornecedor para descarte correto ou para garantia, minha necessidade porém é exibir também os suprimentos que forma comprados mas que ainda não foram enviados para algum cliente ou retornado para o fornecedor, no modo que eu montei a `Query` eu seleciono somente os suprimentos que tiveram a trilha completa:

**Compra -> Venda -> Retorno Fornecedor**

É possível adaptar essa `Query` para que ela me retorne também as seguintes situações:

**Compra -> Venda**

E também quanto o suprimento for somente comprado:

**Compra**

Comment: Possivelmente respondida em [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Answer (score 0):

O que você deve fazer é colocar LEFT JOIN na tabelas que não existem dados, exemplo:

```
SELECT 
    CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, CAMPO4, CAMPO5, CAMPO6
FROM
    TABELA T1
INNER JOIN 
    TABELA T2 ON T2.CAMPO = T1.CAMPO
LEFT JOIN 
    TABELA T3 ON T3.CAMPO = T2.CAMPO
```

Comment: Tu teria como adaptar isso para minha query? Não entendi muito bem como funciona o INNER JOIN e o LEFT JOIN

Comment: Não sei bem dentro dessas tabelas o que define **Compra, Venda e Retorno Fornecedor**, mas a idéia geral é que tudo que envolve **Compra** deve ser INNER JOIN (que traz todos os dados que existem na base) e para **Venda e Retorno Fornecedor** deve ser usado o LEFT JOIN (que retorna os dados quando existem na base e **NULL** quando não dá dados correspondentes nas tabelas)